# how to connect my hosted php website to SQL Server Database on my local server

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, xampp

I have a php website hosted in *1and1.com*, but when I connect to our local server database(windows server 2012 and sql server 2012) it gives me no luck, it gives me this error:

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in dbconn.php on line 9.
```

here's my database connection:

```
<?php   

    $serverName='xxx.xxx.00.xx'; //<-- should I include PORT here? 
    $connectionInfo=array(
                    'Database'=>'DBName',
                    'UID'=>'userName',
                    "PWD"=>'Password');

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo); //<-- line 9 here

    if($conn){
        //echo 'Connection Established!<br />';
    }else{
        //echo 'Connection Failed!<br />';
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
    }   

?>
```

Actually, I'm confused what to use.. like should I use *IIS* here or other procedures but for development, I used `XAMPP` to test my website.

I'm new with  this kind of stuff, so if you can provide me some step by step articles for this is much more appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php):

> The SQLSRV extension requires that the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client be installed on the same computer that is running PHP.

Verify that is installed on your server.

Comment: when I run phpinfo on my website I saw that the PDO driver for `sqlsrv` is not ENABLED. so it must be enabled first on 1and1?